# Seperate a character in multiple sentences in R

Tags: r, text, extract

I extracted a character which goes as follows:

```
"Grondtrekken van het Nederlandse strafrecht                                                                 vanaf € 16.95                                                                                                                                                                        Praktisch bestuursrecht                                                                 vanaf € 22.45                                                                                                                                                                        Basisboek bedrijfseconomie                                                                 vanaf € 24.95                                                                                                                                                                        Basisboek Bedrijfseconomie                                                                 vanaf € 70.90                                                             ... <truncated>
```

I want to extract sentences and prices such that I get an data.frame in the form like:
Name = "Grondtrekken van het Nederlandse strafrecht" Price = 16.95

Name = " Praktisch bestuursrecht" Price = 22.45

etc...

I have problems with separating the sentences. I tried with gsub, but cannot get the desired result.

Comment: What is the source of your price data?  Your provided sample data doesn't seem to have this.

Comment: If scroll further to the right than you'll see the prices (in euros), problem is that there is a lot of space between them

Comment: Then please format your data so we can read it.  We should not have to do this for you.

Comment: So after a sentence there is large empty space followed by "vanaf €XX,XX"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution manipulating the string using `stringr` package

1. Split the string after a price to create a vector of data
2. Extract what is before the price (before `vanaf`)
3. Extract the price using a regex with `\\d`

```r
string  <- "Grondtrekken van het Nederlandse strafrecht                                                                 vanaf € 16.95                                                                                                                                                                        Praktisch bestuursrecht                                                                 vanaf € 22.45                                                                                                                                                                        Basisboek bedrijfseconomie                                                                 vanaf € 24.95                                                                                                                                                                        Basisboek Bedrijfseconomie                                                                 vanaf € 70.90"

library(stringr)
# for pipe 
library(magrittr)
# split after price
vec <- str_split(string, "(?<=\\d)\\s")[[1]] %>%
  # delete repeated spaces
  str_squish()

vec
#> [1] "Grondtrekken van het Nederlandse strafrecht vanaf \200 16.95"
#> [2] "Praktisch bestuursrecht vanaf \200 22.45"                    
#> [3] "Basisboek bedrijfseconomie vanaf \200 24.95"                 
#> [4] "Basisboek Bedrijfseconomie vanaf \200 70.90"

data.frame(
  # extract what is before vanaf
  Name = str_extract(vec, ".*(?=vanaf)") %>% str_trim(),
  # extract price
  Price = str_extract(vec, "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") %>% as.numeric()
)
#>                                          Name Price
#> 1 Grondtrekken van het Nederlandse strafrecht 16.95
#> 2                     Praktisch bestuursrecht 22.45
#> 3                  Basisboek bedrijfseconomie 24.95
#> 4                  Basisboek Bedrijfseconomie 70.90
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: That almost does the trick, but now the it seems the price is identic for every row.